# Alpine.js xcollapse not working with laravel component and p tag

Tags: alpine.js

If I use the p tag and component, the collapse always is open

```html
<div x-data="{ expanded: false }">
    <x-nav-link @click="expanded = ! expanded" :href="'#'" :active="false">{{ __('Collapse') }}</x-nav-link>

    <!-- This is not working -->
    <p x-show="expanded" x-collapse>
        <x-nav-link :href="'/'" :active="false" :sub="true">{{ __('Sub') }}</x-nav-link>
    </p>

    <!-- This is working -->
    <div x-show="expanded" x-collapse>
        <x-nav-link :href="'/'" :active="false" :sub="true">{{ __('Sub') }}</x-nav-link>
    </div>
</div>
```

the console doesn't show any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the *<p>* tag contains a component that will surely be delimited by a *<div>* tag (or some other block tag)
When the browser encounters a block tag inside a *<p>* tag, it automatically closes it, with the result that the component will be outside the *<p>* tag and will not be affected by *x-show="expanded"*.
You can figure this out using the browser console (I used a *<div>* instead of your component to test):

[image]

Typically the browser also tries to fix things by adding a new
*<p>* tag to match the closing one which would remain orphaned

A solution could be to insert the component in a non-block type tag. Otherwise the *<\p>* tag must be replaced.

Here some reference to the [*<p>* tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)